# create new relationships along path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Assuming this topology:

```
create
 (mbp {name: "MacBookPro"}),
 (fb {name:"FritzBox"}),
 (eue {name: "1u1"}),
 (inet {name:"Internet"}),
 (mnh {name:"Mannheim"}),
 (hdb {name:"Heidelberg"}),
 (stg {name: "Stuttgart"}),
 (lnd {name:"Lindt"}),
 (ylo {name:"Ylo"}),
 (qvin {name:"Qvin"}),
 (mbp) -[:LNK {bw:100}]->(fb),
 (fb)-[:LNK {bw:32}]->(eue),
 (eue)-[:LNK {bw:10000}]->(inet),
 (inet)-[:LNK {bw:10000}]->(mnh),
 (mnh)-[:LNK {bw:10000}]->(hdb),
 (hdb)-[:LNK {bw:1000}]->(lnd),   // Route option 1
 (mnh)-[:LNK {bw:10000}]->(stg),
 (stg)-[:LNK {bw:10000}]->(lnd),  // Route option 2
 (lnd)-[:LNK {bw:1000}]->(ylo),
 (lnd)-[:LNK {bw:1000}]->(qvin),
 (ylo)-[:LNK {bw:1000}]->(qvin)
```

I can use this query to get the maximum bandwidth path between "MacBookPro" and "Ylo":

```
match (s {name:"MacBookPro"}),
  (t {name:"Ylo"}),
  p=allShortestPaths(s-[*]-t)
  return
    p as path,
    reduce( mini=100000,
            r in relationships(p) |
              case when mini < r.bw then mini else r.bw end)
        as maximal_bandwidth
  order by maximal_bandwidth desc
  limit 1;
```

How can I create new relationships (e.g. `SESSION_RTP`) along all nodes of that path?

Following Snowburnts suggestion, I came up with this partial solution:

```
match (s {name:"MacBookPro"}),
  (t {name:"Ylo"}),
   p=allShortestPaths(s-[*]-t)
   with
   p as path,
   reduce( mini=100000,
           r in relationships(p) |
             case when mini < r.bw then mini else r.bw end)
        as maximal_bandwidth
  order by maximal_bandwidth desc limit 1
  foreach( r in relationships(path)| set r.session = 1 )
```

Followed by:

```
match (a)-[r:LNK {session : 1}]->(b) create (a)-[:SESSION_RTP{id:1}]->(b)
```

Is it possible to compress this in a single statement?

Comment: you just want all the nodes in that particular path of the match query to be connected by session_key right?

Comment: You can use 

   ' FOREACH (n IN relationships(path) | SET n.SESSION_RTP="a")'

and add a property to every relationship in that path

then you can do 

   ' MATCH (a)-[r:LNK {SESSION_RPT:"a"}]->(b)
    CREATE (a)-[r:SESSION_RPT]->(b)'

I'm not sure how you could apply it to a single path though.

Answer (score 0):

**After reading comment**

I understood that only the path with minimum bw should have nodes connected with relation called `SESSION_RIP`.

Try below

```
match (s {name:"MacBookPro"}),
  (t {name:"Ylo"}),
   p=allShortestPaths(s-[*]-t)
   with
   p as path,
   reduce( mini=100000,
           r in relationships(p) |
             case when mini < r.bw then mini else r.bw end)
        as maximal_bandwidth
  order by maximal_bandwidth desc limit 1
  with relationships(p) as rels
  foreach (t in rels | 
  foreach (a in [startNode(t)]| 
  foreach (b in [endNode(t)]| 
  CREATE a-[:SESSION_RTP]->b
  )))
```

Comment: Trying your query i get the following error `Invalid input 's': expected 'n/N' (line 4, column 57)
"  with nodes(p) as pathNodes, range(1, count(nodes(p)) as nodeRange"`

Comment: Sorry, I'm relatively new to cypher, but wouldn't your suggested solution connect all nodes of _all shortest paths_ with the `SESSION_RTP` relationship? I can't confirm my suspicion, because your query would not run on my neo4j 2.0.0.

Comment: Trying your current solution yields: `p not defined (line 11, column 28)
"  match a where a in nodes(p)"
                            ^`

Comment: The errors are getting more interessting: `Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailure`